# Check entry exist in multiple table using laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any other way to written this code like laravel expert

```
$dncExist   =   DB::table('dnc_table1')
                   ->where('phone_number', '=', $phone)
                   ->get();

if(count($dncExist) == 0)
{
      $dncExist   =   DB::table('dnc_table2')
                         ->where('phone_number', '=', $phone)
                         ->get();
}
```

Comment: What's the reason you have 2 tables with the same content? Why not merge those tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dncExist   =   DB::table('dnc_table1')
                   ->where('phone_number', $phone)
                   ->first();

if(is_null($dncExist))
{
      $dncExist   =   DB::table('dnc_table2')
                         ->where('phone_number', $phone)
                         ->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way.

```
if (!(YourMOdelName::where('phone_number', $phone )->exists())) {

  $dncExist   =   DB::table('dnc_table2')
                         ->where('phone_number', $phone)
                         ->first();
}
```

Or

```
    $dncExist   =  DB::table('dnc_table1')
                   ->where('phone_number', $phone)
                   ->first();

   if(!empty( dncExist )){

      $dncExist   =   DB::table('dnc_table2')
                         ->where('phone_number', $phone)
                         ->first();
}
```

Comment: I like the first one, but can we use any join query or just check single query for check

Comment: You can do the joining before in a variable then call the exist function in the conditions